# okta-oauth-state and okta-oauth-nonce values not coming in cookies after validating login in OKTA

Tags: authentication, okta, okta-api

I'm using python based OKTA login. Once user is validated and we get a response from OKTA. Currently my code is working fine on localhost but I'm not receiving "okta-oauth-state" and "okta-oauth-nonce" while using live application URL. And hence login is failing.

```
        cookie_state = request.COOKIES["okta-oauth-state"]
        cookie_nonce = request.COOKIES["okta-oauth-nonce"]
       

        # # Verify state
        if state != cookie_state:
            raise Exception("Value {} does not match the assigned state".format(state))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_controller'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the live application running on HTTPS? Those cookies are flagged secure and thus will not send over HTTP.